# Show one div and hide another if label = empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been able to effectively show a div if a label is empty (which informs the user no internet connection has been found) which is what I want.

However, I also want to hide `#activateform` if label is empty.

With my current set-up `#activateform` gets hidden when the function runs even if the label is populated which is not what I want. I tried using if statement (see bottom code block) but haven't been able to get it working.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
   <label id="internet_ipaddr" for="internet_ipaddr" class="tbh"></label>
   <h4> You don't seem to be connected to the internet </h4>
</div>

<div id="activateform"> This has to be hidden if label = empty </div>
```

And my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("div.form-group label.tbh:empty").parent().show();
    $("#activateform").hide();
  },2000);
});
```

And my attempt to make it only if label = empty:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  if $("div.form-group label.tbh").empty() {
    $("#activateform").hide();
  }
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `empty()` function delete all content from the selected elements and **do not return a boolean** but the selected elements after the remove of all the content. So your condition `if $("div.form-group label.tbh").empty() {` would never be true because the label element it's not false.

You can use the `html()` function, that return the content of an element and compare this value with an empty string, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($("div.form-group label.tbh").html() == "") {
            $("#activateform").hide();
        }
},2000);
```

Ref:

[the empty() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_empty.asp)

[the html() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method and [`:empty` selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var elem = $("div.form-group label.tbh");
  if (elem.is(':empty')) {
    elem.parent().hide();
    $("#activateform").hide();
  } else {
    elem.parent().show();
  }
  //Rest of your code
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
  <label id="internet_ipaddr" for="internet_ipaddr" class="tbh"></label>
  <h4> You don't seem to be connected to the internet </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, so this toggles form-group, how do I hide activateform div if form-group is shown?

Answer (score 1):

The `empty()` method is not for checking if the element is empty, it is for removing all its content (i.e. emptying it). To check if it is empty, you can use `is(':empty')`, similar to what you used in your first attempt.

Note: I don't know why you're delaying it by 2 seconds using `setTimeout`, but I kept that code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var label = $("div.form-group label.tbh");
    if ($("div.form-group label.tbh").is(':empty')) {
      label.parent().show();
      $("#activateform").hide();
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
  <label id="internet_ipaddr" for="internet_ipaddr" class="tbh"></label>
  <h4> You don't seem to be connected to the internet </h4>
</div>
<div id="activateform"> This has to be hidden if label = empty</div>
```